# Copy range to a new workbook

Tags: vba

I am trying to copy a range from one workbook to another. However I get a run-time error that my subscript is out of range. This is the offending line:

```
Set wbDest = Workbooks("newFile.xlsx")
```

What am I missing?

Code

```
Dim wbDest As Workbook
Dim ws2 As Worksheet

Set myRange = Range("A1", Cells(LastRow, LastCol).Address)' Values retrieved from function
Set wbDest = Workbooks("newFile.xlsx")'both newFile and Thisworkbook stored on my desktop
Set ws2 = wbDest.Sheets("Sheet 1")
ws2.Range("A1") = wsJournals.myRange.Value
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [VBA: Subscript out of range](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25313021/vba-subscript-out-of-range)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you open a workbook, you need to make sure you give the entire path of the workbook and also open it. Following is the syntax,

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Users\user1\Desktop\Book1.xlsx")
Set ws = wb.Sheets("sheet1")
```

Then you can use the `ws` to choose specific cells and do other stuff. It worked for me.