# Open a specific Excel worksheet corresponding to a number in a textbox with a command button

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I have a form which as a textbox named "Core Serial Number"

I have a folder that contains two Excel spreadsheets, with the folder name, and the Excel spreadsheet name that are the same as the core serial number displayed in the text box.

e.g.

- Core Serial Number Displayed in textbox on form = `CAE540151`
- Folder located on A:\ Drive = `CAE540151`
- Excel worksheet located in folder = `CAE540151`.

The form is linked to a master Excel spreadsheet, which is updated daily, and any data that is changed in the master Excel spreadsheet is replicated on the form.

What I would like to do is creating a command button on the form that will allow me to open the Excel worksheet located in the folder on `A:\` drive that corresponds to the core serial number displayed in the textbox.

Is this possible? I am using Access 2013

Answer (score 0):

Here is where I started: http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=17905

I had a button named Command3 and a textbox named Text1.

```
Private Sub Command3_Click()

    Dim strLocation As String

    strLocation = "A:\CAE540151\" & Trim(Text1.Value)

    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim xlWB As Excel.Workbook
    Set xlApp = New Excel.Application

    With xlApp
        .Visible = True
        Set xlWB = .Workbooks.Open(strLocation, , False)
    End With
```

End Sub

The textbox contained the full name of the file (ie CAE540151.xlsx).

You will need to have a reference to Microsoft Excel. You can set that from the VBA menu by choosing Tools and then References.

Comment: For handling and building paths I recommend using the Microsoft Scripting Library, See http://stackoverflow.com/a/27253817/380384