# Updating Code from Excel 2011 to Excel 2019

Tags: excel, vba, macos

We have been using some VBA Code in microsoft Excel 2011 with no faults for a long time. 
We are in the process if upgrading to Office 2019 but the VBACode keeps giving me errors. Eg when using the very simple code shown below to save the current file as WRS.xls

I have tried saving the file as a .xlsm

```
Private Sub CommandButton14_Click()
UserForm1.Hide
ChDir "/Volumes/frontoffice/Trading Activity"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="/Volumes/frontoffice/Trading Activity/WRS.xls" _
        , Password:="", WriteResPassword:="", _
        ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, CreateBackup:=False
    Application.Run "WRS.xls!Back_to_Switcboard"
End Sub
```

I get a

> Runtime Error 1004 Cannot access read only document message

If I delete the existing file called WRS.xls before executing the code the code works - but that is not what i need to achieve

Comment: What do you need to achieve if you don't intent to overwrite the existing file?

Comment: Try explicitly deleting the existing file first? A number of things had to change in Excel for Mac, because of how Apple now forces a sandboxed environment for applications - this looks like it could be one of them.

Comment: I am scared to see that trading activity is handled with Excel/VBA and the myriad of quirks and bugs it has. Yikes!

Comment: Thanks Mathieu How can I explicitly delete the existing file first please ?

Comment: Thanks ja72 - You are right the idea is to overwrite the file, I mean i do not want to have to manually delete it each time

Comment: If you are in windows environment you have access to a [FileSystemObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/filesystemobject-object) by importing the [Microsoft Scripting Runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5798392/380384) library and using operations such as `.DeleteFile()`

Comment: HI ja72  We are using excel for Mac,