# File path when & "\" - Runtime Error 76 Path not found

Tags: excel, vba

The file path doesn't work when:

```vb
Path = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C2").Value & "\"
```

The file path in C2 doesn't include \ at the end

```vb
Sub Make_Folders_And_SubFolders()

Dim GPath, GName, UName, UGroup As String
Dim UserID, Groups, G, U As Range
Dim Gcounter, Ucounter As Integer

GPath = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C2").Value & "\"

On Error GoTo Finish
If Len(GPath) = 0 Or Right(GPath, 1) <> "\" Then
Finish:
    MsgBox "Please, check if:" & vbNewLine _
    & "1- Folder Path is empty." & vbNewLine _
    & "2- or "" \ "" is missing at the end of the path." & vbNewLine _
    & "3- or Path does not exist.", vbCritical
    Exit Sub
End If

Set Groups = Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(5, "P"), Cells(Rows.Count, "P").End(xlUp))
Set UserID = Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(5, "Q"), Cells(Rows.Count, "Q").End(xlUp))

For Each G In Groups
    GName = Trim(G.Value) & "_Group"
    If Len(Dir(GPath & GName, vbDirectory)) > 0 Then
        GoTo Nxt1
    Else
        MkDir GPath & GName
        Gcounter = Gcounter + 1
    End If

Nxt1:
Next G

For Each U In UserID
    UName = Trim(U.Value)
    UGroup = Trim(U.Offset(0, 1).Value) & "_Group"
    If Len(Dir(GPath & UGroup & "\" & UName, vbDirectory)) > 0 Then
        GoTo Nxt2
    Else
        MkDir GPath & UGroup & "\" & UName
        Ucounter = Ucounter + 1
    End If

Nxt2:

Next U

If Gcounter + Ucounter = 0 Then
    MsgBox "All Folders exist, " & vbNewLine & "No folder to be created"
Else
    MsgBox "Job Done !!" & vbNewLine _
      & "Group Folders created: = " & Gcounter & vbNewLine _
      & "User ID Folders created: = " & Ucounter, _
      Title:="Foders Created Count"
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Can we see the value in `C2` and how you are using it?

Comment: @VBasic2008 C:\Users\myuser\Documents\OneDrive - mycompany\txt\folder1

Comment: @VBasic2008 Added it! (:

Comment: What is the error? 70, 76, 53?

Comment: @VBasic2008 Error 76

Comment: Path not found means that there is a problem with your path. It could be a network drive that is not connected or it could just be a problem with the path in your code or a filename with illegal characters in it.

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest for file operations and path building use a [`FileSystemObject`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5798392/380384). It absolutely negates the need to have `\` on the end of paths, as it is smart enough to add it when needed. Specifically, the `fso.BuildPath()` method was designed to suit this exact need.

```
Public Sub CombinePathTest()

    Dim path As String, fn As String
    
    path = fso.GetParentFolderName(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C2").Value)
    
    fn = fso.BuildPath(path, Uname)

End Sub
```

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/filesystemobject-object), you can see there are a lot of helpful functions that take the stress out of building paths, opening files, creating or deleting, or check for existence.

[image: fig]

and by defining as a reference, and adding a global `fso` object you have access to Intellisense while writing code

[image: fig2]

Answer (score -1):

Try the following. Note that I haven't touched anything from `For Each G In Groups` to the end.

```vb
Sub FileOperation()
    
    Dim GPath As String, GName As String, UName As String, UGroup As String
    Dim UserID As Range, Groups As Range, G As Range, U As Range
    Dim Gcounter As Long, Ucounter As Long
    Dim pSep As String: pSep = Application.PathSeparator
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
        
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    GPath = ws.Range("C2").Value

    If Len(GPath) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Path is empty.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If Right(GPath, 1) <> pSep Then
        GPath = GPath & pSep
    End If
    
    Set Groups = ws.Range(ws.Cells(5, "P"), ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "P").End(xlUp))
    Set UserID = ws.Range(ws.Cells(5, "Q"), ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "Q").End(xlUp))
    
    For Each G In Groups
            GName = Trim(G.Value) & "_Group"
            If Len(Dir(GPath & GName, vbDirectory)) > 0 Then
                    GoTo Nxt1
            Else
                    MkDir GPath & GName
                    Gcounter = Gcounter + 1
            End If
    
Nxt1:
    Next G
    
    For Each U In UserID
            UName = Trim(U.Value)
            UGroup = Trim(U.Offset(0, 1).Value) & "_Group"
            If Len(Dir(GPath & UGroup & "\" & UName, vbDirectory)) > 0 Then
                    GoTo Nxt2
            Else
                    MkDir GPath & UGroup & "\" & UName
                    Ucounter = Ucounter + 1
            End If
    
Nxt2:
    
    Next U
    
    If Gcounter + Ucounter = 0 Then
            MsgBox "All Folders exist, " & vbNewLine & "No folder to be created"
    Else
            MsgBox "Job Done !!" & vbNewLine _
            & "Group Folders created: = " & Gcounter & vbNewLine _
            & "User ID Folders created: = " & Ucounter, _
            Title:="Foders Created Count"
    End If

End Sub
```